# Why does this SFINAE give an error in gcc?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Consider the following example (https://godbolt.org/z/pSTUZI):

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct falsy : std::false_type {};

template <
  typename T,
  typename std::enable_if<falsy<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void f(std::back_insert_iterator<T>) {}

template <typename T>
void f(T) {}

struct S {};

int main() {
  S s;
  f<S>(s);
}
```

Compiling it with gcc 8.3 or earlier gives an error:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/iterator:63,

                 from <source>:1:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h: In instantiation of 'class std::back_insert_iterator<S>':

<source>:19:9:   recursively required by substitution of 'template<class T, typename std::enable_if<falsy<T>::value, int>::type <anonymous> > void f(std::back_insert_iterator<_Container>) [with T = S; typename std::enable_if<falsy<T>::value, int>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'

<source>:19:9:   required from here

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:490:7: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct S'

       operator=(const typename _Container::value_type& __value)

       ^~~~~~~~

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/include/c++/8.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:497:7: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct S'

       operator=(typename _Container::value_type&& __value)

       ^~~~~~~~
```

while clang and gcc 9 compile it without any errors. Is this example a correct use of SFINAE and is it a bug in gcc < 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This results from a language defect that was [fixed retroactively](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0929r2.html).  While `T`=`S` is substituted immediately in each declaration, there’s no reason (now that abstractness is not important to a function **type**) to **instantiate** `std::back_insert_iterator<S>` until overload resolution (which needs to know how one might be constructed), which never happens because deduction fails when preparing the default value for the unnamed template parameter.  There is a [similar example](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#call-10.example-1) in the standard involving a return type that would be a hard error if deduction didn’t fail before it is examined (by substitution in this case).

Comment: How is this related to abstract classes from P0929R2 (the first link)?

Comment: @vitaut: If a function type is invalid because a parameter is abstract, *that* is a SFINAE-able error, so it matters whether the class is abstract and it must be instantiated so as to find out.

Comment: That part I understand. I was wondering how is P0929R2 related to my example.

Comment: @vitaut: The behavior of your example hinges on whether the iterator class is instantiated before deduction fails and the function template is discarded.  P0929R2 removes a rule about a function **type** (relevant during substitution because it is [what SFINAE detects](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#8.sentence-2)), so the abstractness no longer [affects the semantics of the program](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#1.sentence-1) and the instantiation doesn’t happen (until overload resolution, if that happens).

Answer (score 1):

It does look like it should compile, as the entire function should be rejected for that insantiation and the compiler should not proceed to instantiate the function's argument templates.

However, clang compiles this code, while gcc 8.3 rejects it (no gcc 9 on my system), so it looks like it might be a bug. A bug that is squashed in gcc 9, though.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct falsy : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct back_insert_iterator {
      back_insert_iterator&
      operator=(typename T::value_type&& __value)
      {
      }
};

template <
  typename T,
  typename std::enable_if<falsy<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void f(back_insert_iterator<T>) {
    back_insert_iterator<T>::value;
}

template <typename T>
void f(T) { }

struct S {};

int main() {
  S s;
  f<S>(s);
}
```